# __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I saw similar questions but in my case there is not even "init" function in my code. How to solve this problem? The problem is with line `(EC.element_to_bo_clickable)`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.get("https://cct-103.firebaseapp.com/")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until
(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiButton-label"))

element.click()
```

Comment: please add a full exception stack trace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the definition, [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L276) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**:

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False
```

So instead of:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiButton-label"))
```

You need to  (add an extra parentheses):

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiButton-label")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing: `()`, in this argument: `((By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiButton-label"))`.

Try the bellow code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://cct-103.firebaseapp.com/")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiButton-label")))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

[element_to_be_clickable()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#element_to_be_clickable) calls internally to `visibility_of_element_located`

```
def __call__(self, driver):
    element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
```

Which call `_find_element`

```
def __call__(self, driver):
    try:
        return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
```

Which in turn call to `find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None)` in `webdriver.py`

```
def _find_element(driver, by):
    try:
        return driver.find_element(*by)
```

This means you need to send a tuple as parameter

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiButton-label")))
```