# How can I fix this syntax error using WebDriverWait in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, syntax-error, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm a beginner in learning python and have a problem with my code.
It seems like a simple error but I cannot find a solution for this error.

Here's a code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.jp/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('Selenium')

  File "<ipython-input-12-1cac2821f197>", line 4
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

search_box.submit()


driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Selenium - Web Browser Automation").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

The problem is on line 6.
I tried to run the code, but it says "search_box" is invalid syntax.
Does anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: Are you missing a closing parenthesis at the end of line 5?

Comment: Post the entire traceback. We are used to spotting errors with the information it provides.

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))` Count the `(`s and `)`s.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors are frequently on the lines above, especially when those lines include parenthesis. A trick is to count opening and closing parens. If the result isn't zero, you've got a problem:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))
             ^          ^      ^                              ^^            ^^
             1          0      1                              23            21
```

Comment: thanks! I could fix my code, but then another problem happened. Its says "name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined" "WebDriverWait" is supposed to be one of python's syntax. isn't it? I don't understand.

Comment: Python has keywords like "for" and "if" and a few builtin objects like "open", but mostly you are dealing with functions and classes that need to be imported. `from selenium import webdriver` is a good example. I don't know selenium specifically or where "WebDriverWait" comes from. You'll need to go back to the tutorials that use it and look for the `import`  statement.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))
```

there is an closing bracket in the end missing.
And WebDriverWait isn't imported yet:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things as follows:

- Once you induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) you don't have to use `find_element_by_*` again. So you can remove the line:

  ```
  search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
  ```
- As you intent to interact with the element instead of `presence_of_element_located()` you need the [expected_conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) of `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- Moreover, [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L276) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**:

  ```
  class element_to_be_clickable(object):
      """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it."""
      def __init__(self, locator):
          self.locator = locator

      def __call__(self, driver):
          element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
          if element and element.is_enabled():
              return element
          else:
              return False
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903422/init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-using-webdriverwait-and/57903495#57903495)

---

### Solution

You can club up the required three(3) lines into a single line as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys('Selenium')
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you Debanjan! I totally forgot to add                                                                            from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC                                            now my code works properly