# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" using WebDriverWait for link_text in Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, expected-condition, linktext

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. I have been browsing and searching for every possible answer to this question on SO, and I figured at this point I should just ask a question, as I have been at this wall for days now. I am currently working on a web scraping project with Selenium in Python. I have already scraped one website and am currently on the second, and I have run into a seemingly  intractable issue. The following code works perfectly fine with no errors on the page https://www.spd.de/standpunkte/:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Familien").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until("Familien").click()
```

Meanwhile, the following code throws the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` on the page https://www.spd.de/standpunkte/familie/:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mehr erfahren").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until("Mehr erfahren").click()
```

The error occurs on the line `WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until("Mehr erfahren").click()`. Based on my research up to now, I figure the specific issue is that something in this line is being interpreted as a `str` object, and is therefore unable to be called. There are, as I see it, two issues:

1. I don't see any reason for this line to produce the error while the code on top, scraping the same website, but on a different page, works without issue. I checked and made sure there are no hidden elements on the page that are being clicked instead.
2. I don't know what in the line is being treated as a `str` object. The whole line? Only part of it? If so, which part? Exacerbating this is that I can't really break down the line to see anything about it; both `print(WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until("Mehr erfahren").click())` and `print(type(WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until("Mehr erfahren").click()))` just end up giving the error. I was able to determine that the `.click()` method is not the issue, as I tried setting the line to be equal to a variable, and then interacted with the variable, but that still produced the error on the same line as before; it never even got to the line with the `.click()` method.

Is there any way I can determine which part of the line is being interpreted as a `str`? Or is that even the issue at all?

This has been driving me crazy, so assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your research was in the right direction.

In your first usecase, the line within `try` was successful:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Familien").click()
```

So the line within `except` was never called:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until("Familien").click()
```

Hence you don't see the error.

---

In your second use-case, the line within `try` wasn't successful:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Familien").click()
```

So the line within `except` was called:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until("Mehr erfahren").click()
```

which results into the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

---

### Deep Dive

[WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) is invoked inconjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions).

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)
- [WebDriverWait not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)

Now, [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L276) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**:

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False
```

So instead of:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until("Mehr erfahren").click()
```

You need to  (add an extra parentheses):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.LINK_TEXT, "Mehr erfahren"))).click()
```

> You can find a detailed discussions in [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903422/init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-using-webdriverwait-and/57903495#57903495)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I will look more into the specifics of WebDriverWait. One issue with this solution, though, is that `WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Mehr erfahren"))).click()` results in a TimeoutException, even when I significantly increase the length of the wait. Does that mean this element is simply not clickable? I don't see how that could be the case, as I can click on it just fine normally.

Comment: @Spencer Somehow I missed your comment. You are seeing _TimeoutException_ exception as the element wasn't found. You may have to use some other locator strategy or may have to refine the existing one. You can raise a new question with all the details. SO contributors will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/941dc9c6b2e2aa4f701c1b72be8de03d4b7e996a/py/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py#L63). From the source

```py
def until(self, method, message=''):
    ...
```

`until` takes a method (i.e. something callable). So, when `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mehr erfahren").click()` raises an exception, it will attempt to call `...until("Mehr erfahren")...`. Since `until` expects a method it will try to call the string you gave it - raising the error that's been driving you crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

I think until expects a conditional (and WebDriverWait waits until that condition is true). You're just passing a string as your argument instead of a condition. You need a condition that checks if that element exists on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css selector: `a[href*="familien"]`

This can be used for both your URLs.

```
driver.get('yourURL')
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href*="familien"]'))).click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    # handle if the element not exist
    print('element not exist')
```

See documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to know how to use `WebDriverWait`