# Selenium Python TypeError: 'str' object is not callable using Python version 3.8 and Selenium version 4.3.0

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, typeerror

I have Googled this many times and am unable to figure this out.
I have the following code and am trying to pull the element based on either the specific string or a piece of the string.  The id and data-id can change so those are not usable.
I have tried lots of variations of the same thing but continue to get the str object is not callable.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(("This is my text (Make a selection)")]')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Make a selection')]")
```

HTML:

```
<li id="li_L2_SR_6">
    <input name="intent1" type=
    "radio" data-id="L2_SR_6">
    "This is my text (Make a selection)"
</li>
```

Comment: You are not using the `find_element` function correctly: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(("This is my text (Make a selection)"')`

Answer (score -1):

This [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62946395/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-using-webdriverwait-for-link-text-in-s) message...

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

...indicates you have passed incorrect argument type.

[find_element()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136633/7429447) takes two arguments, the [`By`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) implementation and the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver).

---

### Solution

As per the HTML:

```
<li id="li_L2_SR_6">
    <input name="intent1" type="radio" data-id="L2_SR_6">
    "This is my text (Make a selection)"
...
...
</li>
```

To identify the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- *xpath* using the text *`This is my text`*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(., 'This is my text')][.//input[starts-with(@name, 'intent') and @type='radio']]")
  ```
- *xpath* using the text *`Make a selection`*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(., 'Make a selection')][.//input[starts-with(@name, 'intent') and @type='radio']]")
  ```

---

### Update

To print the element text:

- *xpath* using the text *`This is my text`*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(., 'This is my text')][.//input[starts-with(@name, 'intent') and @type='radio']]").text)
  ```
- *xpath* using the text *`Make a selection`*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(., 'Make a selection')][.//input[starts-with(@name, 'intent') and @type='radio']]").text)
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked.  Wish I would have asked this earlier.

Comment: undetected Selenium, how can I use the whole text to find the element - I have tried escaping the parenthesis with no luck.  'This is my text /(Make a selection/)'.  Also, is it possible to print the text from this element?  For example, with //li[contains(., 'Make a selection') I would like to print `This is my text (Make a selection)`

Comment: @EricSmith there are two entirely different questions, 1) how can I use the whole text to find the element & 2) is it possible to print the text from this element. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement please.

Comment: I have requirements for both but if I could get 2)the text from the element that may help with requirement 1.  Thanks

Comment: @EricSmith Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: This is giving me InvalidSelectorException.

Comment: There was a typo which I corrected. Retest and let me know the result.

Comment: What was the typo?  I am getting the same error and they look the same.  This is my first post to stackoverflow so it might be user error.

Comment: my bad, I updated the first two locators but didn't update the last two. Please check now.

Answer (score -1):

There is no link but you are using 'a' tag. Please try with

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//li[text()='This is my text \\(Make a selection\\)']"))
```

Even this will also work

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//li[contains(.,'This is my text')]"))
```