# __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given trying to wait for an element using presence_of_element_located()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

The log throw me this :

```
element.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH("//*[@id='menu-item-9145']/a'")))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Code trials:

```
class Descaro:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def Descaro(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='splashModal']/a[1]").click()
        print("deberia estar en la pagina de fondo")
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        element.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH("//*[@id='menu-item-9145']/a'")))
        element.click()
```

I already try this:

```
element.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu-item-9145"]/a'')))
```

but doesn't work too , beacuse:

```
__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things:

- [`presence_of_element_located()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L276) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**
- [`presence_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) doesn't ensures that the element is **interactable**. Instead you need to use [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613)

---

### Solution

You need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='menu-item-9145']/a"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903422/init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-using-webdriverwait-and/57903495#57903495)

Comment: ty man !! i change it  and works , the problem was trying to define this into a variable ("elemento")  finally instead elemento = webdriver......etc  i put your line and works  , very appreciated!!