# TypeError exception was thrown here: init() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using explicit wait through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tuples, webdriverwait

I copied a snippet from the selenium python documentation.
Of course I typed it by hand to verify if it is out of date against Python 3.8.6 which python version I am using.
Fortunately not out-of-date.
but a TypeError exception was thrown here:
**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

my snippet as below:(error occurs at the last row)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.liaoxuefeng.com/wiki/1016959663602400/1017602696742912")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, 'brand'))
```

Comment: It's supposed to be `EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'brand'))`, as shown in the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: yes，you're right. I think the brackets are too many, so I deleted it. Because the documentation haven't acclaimed clearly as DebanjanB said below. Anyway, I'll double check the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L276) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**. Effectively, your code will be:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, 'brand'))
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903422/init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-using-webdriverwait-and/57903495#57903495)
- [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given trying to wait for an element using presence_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691357/init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-trying-to-wait-for-an-e/65691415#65691415)

Comment: Quite frankly, shouldn't this have been closed as a duplicate from the referenced links?

Comment: by the way, this is explicit wait, not implicit. of course I don't know if in the initializer, is it implicit?