# SyntaxError using WebDriverWait to click button with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, syntax-error, webdriverwait

Current problem: The code below runs fine until I insert the following code to click an arrow on the product square/profile.

Bigger problem: The code as a whole runs fine, but the dataset is distorted. After some experimenting, I discovered that the distorted data is all located "below the fold." I'm trying to click on the error on each product square/profile in order to expose the otherwise hidden data. I believe if I can do this, the scraper should work and the dataset will no longer be distorted.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

data = []

for y in range(1,3):
    website = f'https://www.knowde.com/b/markets-personal-care/products{y}'
    path = '/Users/kdavid3mbp/Python/chrome_driver64/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.get(website)
    
    for x in range(1,37):
        products = driver.find_elements('xpath', f'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[{x}]')
       
        for product in products:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', '/div/div/svg')).click()
            
            brand = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[1]').text
            item = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[2]').text
            inci_name = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[2]').text
            try:
                ingredient_origin = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[3]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                ingredient_origin = 'null'
            try:
                function = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                function = 'null'
            try:
                benefit_claims = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                benefit_claims = 'null'
            try:
                description = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[3]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                description = 'null'
            try:
                labeling_claims = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                labeling_claims = 'null'
            try:
                compliance = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[6]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                compliance = 'null'
            try:
                hlb_value = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                hlb_value = 'null'
            try:
                end_uses = product.find_element('xpath', '/a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                end_uses = 'null'
            try:
                cas_no = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                cas_no = 'null'
            try:
                chemical_name = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                chemical_name = 'null'
            try:
                synonyms = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[6]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                synonyms = 'null'
            try:
                chemical_family = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                chemical_family = 'null'
            try:
                features = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[7]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                features = 'null'
            try:
                grade = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                grade = 'null'

        dict = {
            'brand': brand,
            'item': item,
            'inci_name': inci_name,
            'ingredient_origin': ingredient_origin,
            'function': function,
            'benefit_claims': benefit_claims,
            'description': description,
            'labeling_claims': labeling_claims,
            'compliance': compliance,
            'hlb_value': hlb_value,
            'end_uses': end_uses,
            'cas_no': cas_no,
            'chemical_name': chemical_name,
            'synonyms': synonyms,
            'chemical_family': chemical_family,
            'features': features,
            'grade': grade
        }

        data.append(dict)
        print('Saving: ', dict['brand'])


# Closes driver once for loop is completed
driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('/Users/kdavid3mbp/Python/cosmetics_data.csv', index=False)
```

The current problem is when inserting the following:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', '/div/div/svg')).click()
```

I get a SyntaxError:

```
  File "/var/folders/90/82_f843n4h9drvxh7z3tqg840000gn/T/ipykernel_34523/1099992952.py", line 22
    brand = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[1]').text
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure how to arrange this so that I click the down arrows. I'd like to click each one for the 36 product squares/profiles on each page.

Comment: The number of opening and closing parentheses in `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', '/div/div/svg')).click()` don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition, [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L276) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**:

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False
```

So instead of:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', '/div/div/svg')).click()
```

You need to  (add an extra parentheses):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', '/div/div/svg'))).click()
                                            # note the additional end of parenthesis ^
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given trying to wait for an element using presence_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691415/7429447)
- [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903495/7429447)
- [TypeError exception was thrown here: init() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using explicit wait through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65705378/7429447)

Comment: Thank you for your input! I've corrected the parentheses issue. I now receive a "TimeoutException" error.

Comment: @kdavid3891 Glad to be able to solve the _`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`_ issue. _`TimeoutException`_ is a different issue all together. Feel free raise a new ticket along with the relevant text based HTML of the element.