# Takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given error using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

Hello I was trying to click on button male on website: https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407
But it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: element_to_be_clickable() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
```

The code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407")

WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//type[@name='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']")).click()
```

Comment: Ok.Found the answer just wrote
```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='q26']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/label").click()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a *tuple* within `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

```
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//type[@name='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']"))
```

However, your working line of code will be:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']"))).click()
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: Male]

---

Moreover, with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) the following line:

```
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver")
```

is now associated with a [*`DeprecationWarning`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918148/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-a-servic/69918489#69918489) as follows:

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

So you need to pass an instance of *`Service`* class as an argument and your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

s = Service('D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']"))).click()
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903422/init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-using-webdriverwait-and/57903495#57903495)
- [Use Selenium with Brave Browser pass service object written in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69970256/use-selenium-with-brave-browser-pass-service-object-written-in-python/69981271#69981271)

Comment: It gives me this error and It doesn't click it
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Puhceto\SeleniumProject\venv\Clicking A Button.py", line 10, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//type[@name='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']"))).click()

Comment: @NikaTheKilla Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tuple you should pass there,

```
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//type[@name='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']")))
```

Comment: It didn't click the button. Error DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver")

Comment: @NikaTheKilla This issue is appearing selenium, pip and python updates, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point maybe, the contents By.XPATH, "//type[@name='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']" should be enclosed in parentheses and have 2 ahead and 3 after the content.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's the structure of the Selenium that makes it very Particular. Check parentheses **(**(By.XPATH, "//type[@name='RESULT_RadioButton-7_0']"))**)**